# Alternative to Pingdom website monitoring service

Tags: monitoring, analytics, load-time, sms, downtime

I need a website monitoring service to make sure my app is not only up but also responsive.  Pingdom is great, but just so expensive.  Is there anything like it but more affordable?

***UPDATE***: I'd like 1 minute interval checks at least. By responsive, I'd like to know stats on the response times of the individual checks and an SMS alert maybe if the responsive stays below a threshold for a certain amount of time.

Comment: http://fmonit.com will come soon. Maybe this is a good opportunity for you..

Comment: I know about http://server-monitoring.online-domain-tools.com/ that allows  1-minute checks and it allows you to set complex rules on the response of the webpage. It shows response times for individual checks but it does not alert in case of slow response times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://uptimerobot.com/ offers a free plan with 5 minute interval checking, with one-minute interval checks on their [paid plans](https://uptimerobot.com/pricing).

If you're really concerned with uptime you might also like to consider DNS hosting with a [DNS failover service,](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/enterprisedns/dnsfailover.html) which monitors your site every 2 to 4 minutes and updates your DNS to point to a backup server should it find that your primary server is down. Of course, this means you need to pay for a backup server, and that you need to mirror the content between the two servers.

Comment: I'll credit you with the best answer, even though the whole point of the question was an "alternative to pingdom" and you suggested pingdom :).  They are fairly expensive though, even their $39.95/mo plan only gives you 200 SMSes and then you have to pay $0.35-0.45 EACH SMS: http://www.pingdom.com/services/extraservices/

Comment: Thanks. Fair comment about having to pay extra for SMS -- that does seem expensive once you go over 200 alerts. If my sites were going down more than 200 times a month, though, I'd probably spend the money on better hosting instead of uptime reporting. Another option might be to use an open source self-hosted reporting system, like Nagios Core: http://www.nagios.com/products/nagioscore/

Comment: Oh -- I didn't realise it was 200 texts on signup, not 200 a month. That does seem a little odd. Probably best to rely on their email reporting and turn push email on, perhaps.

Comment: Even so, figure you consume 5 SMS messages per event, that's still 40 events worth on signup. Even if you had an outage every month, that's more than three years' worth. And an unplanned outage every month seems...too high. (For planned outages you use the API to pause monitoring.)

Comment: @nick there are also good alternatives like http://www.servermonitoring.io (no affiliate). They are essentially free and you also have HTTP checks and PING monitoring as far as I remember. Certainly worth a try IMHO.

Comment: It doesn't appear that pingdom has a fully free plan anymore - seems to be a "14 Day Risk Free Trial"

Comment: @siliconpi Thanks – corrected my answer. https://uptimerobot.com/ is one worth checking out if you're looking for a free offering.

Comment: Another one worth checking our is https://devmonitor.io Many cool features and free for up to 5 websites

Answer (score 7):

Check into UptimeRobot http://www.uptimerobot.com It's free, offers HTTP and ping monitoring every 5 minutes with email, text and RSS notifications.  To my soon to be former webhost's chagrin, it's very reliable with uptime monitoring logs and past event tracking.

Comment: And UptimeRobot has just added an API, making it very useful indeed.

Comment: Their paid plan offers 1 minute intervals now.

Answer (score 2):

[mon.itor.us](http://mon.itor.us/) and [SiteUptime](http://www.siteuptime.com/compare.php) have free/ad-supported plans. Check are only at 30-minute intervals however.

They both have plan upgrades which measure at 5 minute intervals and are cheaper than Pingdom, so you might find a reasonable cost/benefit trade-off.

Answer (score 1):

I use [was it up](http://wasitup.com) (free), and they've always seemed to catch my downtime pretty quickly.  I'm going to pump the emails into [PagerDuty](http://www.pagerduty.com) (not free) to send SMSes as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Love the simplicity, but the faq shows it's 5 minute intervals.