# Third-party site-uptime-checking services

Tags: monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to Pingdom website monitoring service](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11383/alternative-to-pingdom-website-monitoring-service)

To monitor my website I currently use Monastic.com (free, but only does checks something like once a day) and a free account on pingdom.com (free, but limited to a single website).

Are there free services that ping pages on your website and can be used to check for uptime in that manner?  And if there aren't any great free ones available, what are some cheap pay services?  Recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Cloudkick](http://www.cloudkick.com/). It was recently acquired by Rackspace and has since then made some services free.

> Now that external checks are free & unlimited for all plans, you can sign up for a developer account and use Ping, HTTP, HTTPS, DNS, TCP, and SSH checks on as many servers as you want, completely free of charge.

See https://www.cloudkick.com/free-basic-checks

Answer (score 0):

We use [Basic State](http://basicstate.com/) and have been quite happy with their services.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend http://mon.itor.us/ as it offers Free and paid services. It has HTTP, DNS, PING, FTP, SMTP, POP and almost all kind of monitoring service. For monitoring any specific page you can add HTTP monitor with the page URL.