# Live status dashboard for multiple websites

Tags: statistics

Anyone know of a good online service or local software package that will give me a real-time (or almost real-time) status of how my websites are doing: uptime, ping, latency, DNS, etc.

Any recommendations would be great.

Comment: This question is very similar to [Alternative to Pingdom website monitoring service](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11383/alternative-to-pingdom-website-monitoring-service) - if the suggestions for external monitoring services appear adequate, perhaps this question's scope could be limited to locally-hosted software?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is something your webhost company can give you.  I suppose you could build your own, but it would have to be continuously checking the server which will eat up your bandwidth, hence the reason it usually comes from the hosting company.  You might also be able to find a hosting company with APIs that allow you to check these things...

Answer (score 1):

http://chartbeat.com/ is one option, Google Analytics now also has live analytics. You can get it all on one screen using a service like http://www.geckoboard.com/

Answer (score 0):

yes, I use http://ogggy.com designed exactly for what your looking for. Its a multiple website Analytics in one dashboard, I have 300 websites so this solution is perfect for me, i can see which sites are online or offline, my domain expiry dates and loads of drill down stats. its great to see all your traffic and hits from all your websites on one dashboard. its an easy way to compare which sites you need to get more traffic for.